# Maven throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.javac.handlers.HandleAccessors even when I removed lombok completely from my project?

Tags: java, maven

This problem started around 3 days ago.
Somehow, my project wouldn't build with the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.javac.handlers.HandleAccessors"

What I've Tried:

- I've 'delomboked' the entire project and removed lombok from the pom.xml
- Changing the lombok versions to older versions
- Changing the pom.xml files of the modules hoping to somehow fix the error
- Deleting my ~/.m2 directory

Does anyone know a solution for this?
The project dosen't even contain "lombok" anywhere

Full error stacktrace and pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/Badbird-5907/7d331096303d20cbc9790cdaf334a875

Comment: Which JDK version do you use? Where does the exception occur? Test? Or Runtime?

Comment: Java 8, It also occurs on java 15 (probally unrelated but i use the Zulu jvm) this occurs when i do mvn clean package

Comment: Which version of lombok do you use? Second means by `clean package` within a test or compile error?

Comment: I use lombok 1.18.20 but i've removed it. It's a compile error

Comment: So without lombok it works now?

Comment: Can you share pom.xml

Comment: It dosen't work even with lombok removed, pom is now in the original post

Comment: First I see several things which are simply bad like ` <directory>../OctoCore-paper/src/main/resources</directory>` ... trying to access outside the current module is simply wrong...also `<directory>../target</directory>` does not make sense... furthermore `<scope>system</scope>` do not use that...

Comment: about the `../target`, its there because i'm too lazy to go into the `OctoCore-build/target`, i'll fix the `<directory>../OctoCore-paper/src/main/resources</directory>` `<scope>system</scope>`. I should also mention I reverted all my pom.xml files to older versions from when they worked off git/vcs